# Convert interface{} to map

Tags: json, dictionary, interface, go

I am trying to read a json file, the code that does that has something like below

```
var configurations map[string]interface{}

func GetConfigMap(name string) interface{} {
    valueMap := configurations[name]
    return valueMap.(map[string]interface{})
}
```

And I am trying to read the map as below,

```
glossary := jsonreader.GetConfigMap("glossary")
fmt.Println(glossary["GlossDiv"])
```

The json structure is as below,

```
{    "glossary": {
        "title": "example glossary",
        "GlossDiv": {
            "title": "S",
            "GlossList": {
                "GlossEntry": {
                    "ID": "SGML",
                    "SortAs": "SGML",
                    "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
                    "Acronym": "SGML",
                    "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
                    "GlossDef": {
                        "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
                        "GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]
                    },
                    "GlossSee": "markup"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting an exception that says -

```
invalid operation: glossary["GlossDiv"] (type interface {} does not support indexing)
```

How do I make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do based on your question, but can't you just change the return type of the function?

```
func GetConfigMap(name string) map[string]interface{} {
    valueMap := configurations[name]
    return valueMap.(map[string]interface{})
}
```

Comment: You can see in the example I posted, changing the return type of GetConfigMap from interface{} to map[string]interface{} will let you do what you want.